# How to add elements from 3 differents tables in one onClick

Tags: java, android, sqlite, onclick, addition

I want add one page (with title and date) from table "page"

associate it one tag( with only text tag) from table "tag"

I have an associate table "pageTagId "(with id_page and id_tag)

there is my method addPage :

```
public long addPage(Page page){

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(PageSQLITE.COL_DATE_PAGE,page.getDatePage().getTime());
        values.put(PageSQLITE .COL_TITLE_PAGE,page.getTitrePage());
        return bdd.insert(PageSQLITE.TABLE_PAGE, null, values);

    }
```

there is my method addTag :

```
public long addTag(Tag tag) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TagSQLITE.COL_TEXT_TAG, tag.getTextTag());
    return bdd.insert(TagSQLITE.TABLE_TAG, null, values);
}
```

My associate table :

```
   private final static String CREATE_TABLE_LIENS_TAG_PAGE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LIENS_TAG_PAGE + " ("
                    + COL_ID_PAGE + " INTEGER PRIMARY FOREIGN KEY NOT NULL  AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + COL_ID_TAG + " INTEGER PRIMARY FOREIGN KEY NOT NULL  AUTOINCREMENT  );";
```

and associate method :

```
public long insertTagPage(LiensTagPage liensTagPage) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(LiensTagPageSQLITE.COL_ID_PAGE, liensTagPage.getIdPage() );
    values.put(LiensTagPageSQLITE.COL_ID_TAG, liensTagPage.getIdTag() );

    return bdd.insert(PageSQLITE.TABLE_PAGE, null, values);
}
```

My onclick method :

```
public void onClickAdd(View v) {

        strTitle = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTitle)).getText().toString();
        datePage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDate);
        tagPage = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTag)).getText().toString();


Date d = (Date)datePage.getTag();

            Page page = new Page(strTitle, d );
            Tag tag = new Tag (tagPage);
            LiensTagPage lTp = new LiensTagPage(idPage, idTag);

            PageMgr pageMgr = new PageMgr(this);
            TagMgr tagMgr = new TagMgr(this);

            pageMgr.open();
            tagMgr.open();

           long ok = pageMgr.addPage(page);
            tagMgr.addTag(tag);
```

the add working for title and date but when I want add tag in same time than date and title, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `onClickAdd` method do things:

- 1. long pageId = pageMgr.addPage(page);
- 2. long tagId = pageMgr.addTag(tag);
- 3. liensTagPage.setIdPage(pageId);liensTagPage.setIdTag(tagId);
- 4. long id = pageMgr.insertTagPage(liensTagPage);

is this make sense?

Comment: it doesn't work you can't use "long tagId = pageMgr.addTag(tag);"                     
but long tagId = TagMgr.addTag(tag);

Comment: @Valentin I see your  `addPage ` method returns long , that is not a pageId?